# ¿Cómo convertir un número con centésimas en palabras en plsql oracle?

Tags: oracle, plsql

¿Cómo puedo convertir un número con centesimas a letras ? ejemp 15.20 a quince 20/100  cabe mencionar que el número es aleatorio ya que utilizo un parametro para convertir la cantidad.
Actulmente estoy utilizando una consulta que encontre la cual funciona a la perfeccion.

Lo que la consulta hace es, primero, construir una CTE con números de ejemplo, llamado Numero, luego en el CTE PreProcesado1 los separo en dígitos: unidades, decenas, centenas. Para el ejemplo necesitaba solamente los últimos 3, pero he dejado los siguientes tres a manera de ejemplo. De la misma manera puedes obtener las unidades, decenas y centenas de millón, y así hasta la cantidad de dígitos que quieras soportar.

```
    with
Numero as (
select :p_total N from dual
/*union all select 14587 from dual
union all select 14 from dual
union all select 7816 from dual
union all select 174 from dual
union all select 458 from dual
union all select 17548987 from dual
union all select 458157 from dual
union all select 14850 from dual
union all select 21410 from dual
union all select 100 from dual
union all select 457500 from dual
union all select 82100 from dual*/
)
,
PreProcesado1 as (
select   N
       , floor(mod(N, 1000000) / 100000) MillarCentenas
       , floor(mod(N, 100000) / 10000) MillarDecenas
       , floor(mod(N, 10000) / 1000) MillarUnidades
       , floor(mod(N, 1000) / 100) Centenas
       , floor(mod(N, 100) / 10) Decenas
       , floor(mod(N, 10)) Unidades
  from Numero
)
select   N
       , 
       case MillarDecenas
            when 0 then ''
            when 2 then 'veinte mil '
            when 3 then 'treinta  mil'
            when 4 then 'cuarenta mil '
            when 5 then 'cincuenta  mil'
            when 6 then 'sesenta mil'
            when 7 then 'setenta mil'
            when 8 then 'ochenta mil'
            when 9 then 'noventa mil'
            when 1 then
     case MillarUnidades
                when 0 then 'diez mil '
                when 1 then 'once mil '
                when 2 then 'doce  mil'
                when 3 then 'Trece mil'
                when 4 then 'Catorce mil '
                when 5 then 'Quince mil'
                else 'dieci'
              end
          end
       || case when MillarDecenas > 1 and MillarUnidades <> 0 then 'y ' else '' end
       || case 
            when MillarDecenas = 1 and MillarUnidades < 6 then '' 
            else
        case MillarUnidades
            when 0 then ''
            when 1 then 'mil' --case when Centenas = 0 and Decenas = 0 then 'mil ' else 'miles ' end
            when 2 then 'dos mil '
            when 3 then 'tres mil '
            when 4 then 'cuatro mil '
            when 5 then 'cinco mil'
            when 6 then 'seis mil '
            when 7 then 'siete mil '
            when 8 then 'ocho mil '
            when 9 then 'nueve mil '

        end    
    end
    ||
        case Centenas
            when 0 then ''
            when 1 then case when Decenas = 0 and Unidades = 0 then 'cien ' else ' ciento' end
            when 2 then 'doscientos '
            when 3 then 'trescientos '
            when 4 then 'cuatrocientos '
            when 5 then 'quinientos '
            when 6 then ' seiscientos '
            when 7 then 'setecientos '
            when 8 then 'ochocientos '
            when 9 then 'novecientos '
          end
       || case Decenas
            when 0 then ''
            when 2 then 'veinte '
            when 3 then 'treinta '
            when 4 then 'cuarenta '
            when 5 then 'cincuenta '
            when 6 then 'sesenta '
            when 7 then 'setenta '
            when 8 then 'ochenta '
            when 9 then 'noventa '
            when 1 then
              case Unidades
                when 0 then 'diez '
                when 1 then 'once '
                when 2 then 'doce '
                when 3 then 'trece '
                when 4 then 'catorce '
                when 5 then 'quince '
                else 'dieci'
              end
          end
       || case when Decenas > 1 and Unidades <> 0 then 'y ' else '' end
       || case 
            when Decenas = 1 and Unidades < 6 then '' 
            else
              case Unidades 
                when 0 then ''
                when 1 then 'uno'
                when 2 then 'dos'
                when 3 then 'tres'
                when 4 then 'cuatro'
                when 5 then 'cinco'
                when 6 then 'seis'
                when 7 then 'siete'
                when 8 then 'ocho'
                when 9 then 'nueve'
              end
            end 
       NumeroEnLetras
  from PreProcesado1
```

¿Saben como puedo implementar las centésimas?

Comment: Intenta con la función [`xdofx:to_check_number`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/bi.1111/e13881/T527073T558233.htm#T564600).

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.